# Pass parameter from php to casperjs/phantomjs

Tags: php, parameters, exec, phantomjs, casperjs

Edit: I answered my own question, see edit below.

ORIGINAL:
I have phantomjs and casperjs installed on my web server and they both run fine. The script I am planning on creating relise on a user input from my website, which is then passed on to the casperjs script.
After fiddling around a bit, I noticed that I am stuck on the very basic task of the user input. How would pass the variable from php to casperjs?

Please note, the following are just test scripts.

My php script

```
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs hello.js 2>&1',$output);
print_r($output);
```

hello.js

```
var user_input = "http://example.com/";
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false
  }
});

casper.start(user_input, function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

So how would I pass the $user_input to the hello.js. My goal is that the user can input a url which is then being scraped.

Comment: You can post that answer as 'Answer' and accept it. That is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Yes, please post it as self-answer. Your answer is basically correct, but use `escapeshellarg` (even if you know this, someone copy and pasting from your answer in future might not). (E.g. user_input = ';rm -rf /etc/' )

Comment: I had to wait 48 hours until I could answer myself. I fixed it now. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

It seems phantomjs and casperjs support command line arguments http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html

My script now looks like this.

test.php

```
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];

putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
exec('/usr/local/bin/casperjs hello.js $user_input 2>&1',$output);

print_r($output);
```

hello.js

```
var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var address = args[4]; //In my case 4 was the argument for $user_input, yours might be different, depending on your server setup.

var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'error',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false
  }
});

casper.start(address, function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```